# Gradle Daemon stopped working in parallel due to file lock timeouts

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, daemon

Yesterday all of the sudden my projects on a Windows 10 machine stopped running in parallel due to file lock timeouts.

All my projects are using gradle-wrapper and provide a `run` task

When I start the 1st run-task, it work normally, but any following run-tasks break with the error like this:

```
> .\gradlew run
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy and 4 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Gradle could not start your build.
> Could not create service of type FileAccessTimeJournal using GradleUserHomeScopeServices.createFileAccessTimeJournal().
   > Timeout waiting to lock journal cache (C:\Users\injec\.gradle\caches\journal-1). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
     Owner PID: 16440
     Our PID: 12216
     Owner Operation:
     Our operation:
     Lock file: C:\Users\injec\.gradle\caches\journal-1\journal-1.lock
```

the `--status` option shows:

```
> .\gradlew --status
   PID STATUS   INFO
 12216 IDLE     6.9.1
 16440 BUSY     6.9.1
 14992 STOPPED  (stop command received)
  7856 STOPPED  (other compatible daemons were started and after being idle for 0 minutes and not recently used)
 26680 STOPPED  (by user or operating system)
 18556 STOPPED  (by user or operating system)
```

I tried different tricks, like switching the Gradle verison 5.6.1 - 6.8.3 - 6.9.1 and using the `--stop` option, but the error remains.

Adding the `--stacktrace` to the run command reveals that not only `journal-1` cache is involved, but also some others dirs like `modules-2`.

I didn't do any changes to my system, apart from regular Win10 updates.

How can the problem be fixed?

TIA

Comment: By any chance did you start some of the gradle instances with elevated shell (powershell with run-as-admin)?

Comment: no, under default user rights. Usually I start those directly from eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [My comment in a thread](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8750#issuecomment-1490366759) and the rest of discussion.

On my Win11-box I needed to add an exclusion to Antivirus on `C:\Users.gradle\caches` folder to make Gradle run normal again.

Hope this will help someone...

Answer (score 1):

This may be the file-system permissions of `C:\Users\injec\.gradle`... while you may have overseen one detail: you're calling `.\gradlew` instead of `./gradlew` or `gradlew.bat` ...which means that you are not running on CMD, but on PS or WSL. `gradlew.bat run` would run directly on CMD.

Comment: I AM running on Win10 in PowerShell and in CMD

Comment: the results in both shells are the same

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that gradle process was exited abnormally and left the lock file behind. Check in the task manager if process with id `16440` exists, and if not just remove the orphan lock file `C:\Users\injec\.gradle\caches\journal-1\journal-1.lock`

Comment: From what I saw, if the process with `Owner PID` exists, the lock file cannot be deleted. If it doesn't exist, the presence or absence of the lock file has no effect on newly started daemon...

Comment: Some people say that this might be related to firewall or antivirus programs: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8750#issuecomment-915312188

Answer (score 0):

Check .gradle file system. Gradle not works well on non-native file system. https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/15881

> File system watching supports the following file system types:

APFS

btrfs

ext3

ext4

XFS

HFS+

NTFS

Gradle also supports VirtualBox’s shared folders.

Network file systems like Samba and NFS are not supported.

Symlinks
File system watching is not compatible with symlinks. If your project files include symlinks, symlinked files do not benefit from file system watching optimizations.

or you can disable file system watch for the build https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/file_system_watching.html#disable

> Gradle maintains a Virtual File System (VFS) to calculate what needs to be rebuilt on repeat builds of a project. By watching the file system, Gradle keeps the VFS current between builds.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).